# dose ROS support tensorflow-gpu version?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

and ,where can i get the 'ros tensorflow-gpu' related docs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288402/dose-ros-support-tensorflow-gpu-version?/) by [qrf](https://answers.ros.org/users/34614/qrf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS and tensorflow are just coupled over the API.
You can implement something with ROS and tensorflow if you want.

As [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/) as well as ROS contain APIs for C++ and Python, you should be able to implement something within ROS which uses tensorflow with GPU Support.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
There's already quite some activity around ROS + Tensorflow. Perhaps the OP could start there? See: [google.com/search?q=ros+tensorflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=ros+tensorflow).

**Comment by [qrf](https://answers.ros.org/users/34614/qrf/) on 2018-04-13**:
Thanks .That helpls a lot!